# Верстка адаптивного сайта

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка, html5

Народ всем привет, нужна помощь.
Верстаю сайтик с адаптивным дизайном через [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) запросы, все норм получается но проблема появляется тогда когда сайт открывают на телефоне. Минимальная ширина сайта 480px 
используется след. код:

```
@media (max-width: 699px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 699px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .header {
    min-width: 480px;
  }
  .maincontent, .beforefooter, .footer, .footerphonesmall, .afterheader, .preimblock, .tarifblock, .opisblockforpc, .opisblockformid {
    min-width: 480px;
  }
}
```

тут понятно что до 699 дизайн тянется, останавливается на 480 пикселях.

Когда открываем на телефоне сайт то видим то что он почему-то сразу масштабирован и появляется полоса прокрутки горизонтальная.

используется мета тег

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

, user-scalable=no убрал пока.

есть у кого-нибудь совет по решению данной проблемы? хотелось бы чтобы сайт сразу открывался в соответвующем разрешении мин 480px без масштабирования

пациент: ___http://f2g.webkl.ru/

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего на сайте есть блоки, ширина которых на даже на мобильном сайте больше 480 пикселей. Исследуйте в браузерах ширину блоков и также задайте для этих блоков адаптивную ширину